# How to group timestamps by the hour for the last 24 hours?

Tags: algorithm, go, timestamp, grouping, slice

I have a slice of structs. Each struct looks like the following.

```golang
type Log struct {
    Success   bool      `json:"s" bson:"s"`
    Latency   int       `json:"l" bson:"l"`
    Timestamp time.Time `json:"t" bson:"t"`
}
```

The before-mentioned slice contains up to 4000 logs. New logs are pushed at the end of the slice, which means it is already in ascending order.

How can I create a summary of all the logs in the slice, grouped by the hour for the past 24 hours? For every hour I need to know how many logs are available and how many of them are successful. There might be logs that are older than 24 hours.

I need this to create a chart for the last 24 hours, which has a maximum of 24 bars. One for every hour.

Comment: Can you show what you've tried so far?

Answer (score -1):

So to do this, you could do something like the following:

1. Make a couple of maps to store the unique metrics for each hour partition
2. Iterate through the logs, truncate the timestamp to an hour and increment the metrics that you are interested in
3. Compile the metrics into a list and sort them by hour

Here's a complete sample https://play.golang.org/p/x25BwNKQ1X6

```
go run ./main.go
Hour                           Successful  Total
2021-03-04 00:00:00 +0000 UTC  1           1
2021-03-04 01:00:00 +0000 UTC  0           3
2021-03-04 02:00:00 +0000 UTC  0           2
2021-03-04 03:00:00 +0000 UTC  1           5
2021-03-04 04:00:00 +0000 UTC  5           8
2021-03-04 05:00:00 +0000 UTC  1           5
2021-03-04 06:00:00 +0000 UTC  1           3
2021-03-04 07:00:00 +0000 UTC  1           1
2021-03-04 08:00:00 +0000 UTC  2           7
2021-03-04 09:00:00 +0000 UTC  0           1
2021-03-04 10:00:00 +0000 UTC  1           5
2021-03-04 11:00:00 +0000 UTC  0           3
2021-03-04 12:00:00 +0000 UTC  2           4
2021-03-04 14:00:00 +0000 UTC  0           3
2021-03-04 15:00:00 +0000 UTC  3           3
2021-03-04 16:00:00 +0000 UTC  4           6
2021-03-04 17:00:00 +0000 UTC  5           9
2021-03-04 18:00:00 +0000 UTC  3           5
2021-03-04 19:00:00 +0000 UTC  2           6
2021-03-04 20:00:00 +0000 UTC  2           4
2021-03-04 21:00:00 +0000 UTC  5           7
2021-03-04 23:00:00 +0000 UTC  2           6
2021-03-05 00:00:00 +0000 UTC  1           3
```

```golang
// main.go

package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
    "os"
    "sort"
    "text/tabwriter"
    "time"
)

type Log struct {
    Success   bool      `json:"s" bson:"s"`
    Latency   int       `json:"l" bson:"l"`
    Timestamp time.Time `json:"t" bson:"t"`
}

func main() {
    totalCounts := map[time.Time]int{}
    successCounts := map[time.Time]int{}

    for _, entry := range sampleLogs(100) {
        truncatedTs := entry.Timestamp.Truncate(time.Hour)
        totalCounts[truncatedTs] += 1
        if entry.Success {
            successCounts[truncatedTs] += 1
        }
    }

    var summaries HourSummarySlice
    for hour, total := range totalCounts {
        summaries = append(summaries, HourSummary{
            Timestamp:       hour,
            TotalCount:      total,
            SuccessfulCount: successCounts[hour],
        })
    }

    sort.Sort(summaries)
    w := tabwriter.NewWriter(os.Stdout, 4, 0, 2, ' ', 0)
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "Hour\tSuccessful\tTotal\n")
    for _, summary := range summaries {
        fmt.Fprintf(w, "%v\t%d\t%d\n", summary.Timestamp, summary.SuccessfulCount, summary.TotalCount)
    }
    w.Flush()
}

type HourSummary struct {
    Timestamp       time.Time
    TotalCount      int
    SuccessfulCount int
}

// Custom type so we can sort the output.
type HourSummarySlice []HourSummary

func (s HourSummarySlice) Len() int {
    return len(s)
}

func (s HourSummarySlice) Less(i, j int) bool {
    return s[i].Timestamp.Before(s[j].Timestamp)
}

func (s HourSummarySlice) Swap(i, j int) {
    s[i], s[j] = s[j], s[i]
}

func sampleLogs(count int) []Log {
    var output []Log
    start := time.Now().Add(-24 * time.Hour)
    for i := 0; i < count; i++ {
        output = append(output, Log{
            // flip a coin
            Success: rand.Intn(10) > 5,
            // random latency between [500, 1000)
            Latency: 500 + rand.Intn(500),
            // random time offset up to 24hr
            Timestamp: start.Add(time.Duration(rand.Int63n(int64(24 * time.Hour)))).UTC(),
        })
    }
    return output
}
```